# Spanning Tree for graph $G=(V,E)$ with labeled vertices

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

**Input:** $G=(V,E)$ - Connected, undirected graph, $w:V\to \mathbb{R}^+$ weight function on $G$ vertices.

For a Spanning Tree $T=(V,E_T)$ and a vertex $v\in V$, we define $d_T(v)$ as $v$ degree in $T$.

**Output:** A Spanning Tree $T=(V,E_T)$ such that $\sum_{v\in V}{d_T(v) \cdot w(v)}$ is minimal.

My solution is to reduce this problem to the MST-problem by defining $w':E\to\mathbb{R}^+$ such that:

$w'(e={\{u,v}\}) = w(u) + w(v)$

than using an MST-algorithm on $<G, w'>$ will provide me with an MST $T$ such that $\sum_{e\in E_T}w'(e)$ is minimal.

I'm having hard time with formalizing that $\sum_{v\in V}{d_T(v) \cdot w(v)} = \sum_{e\in E_T}w'(e)$.

I will appreciate any direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each vertex $v \in V$, the sum $\sum_{e\in E_T}w'(e)$ includes $w(v)$ once for every edge in $E_T$ where $v$ appears.

So does $\sum_{v \in V} d_T(v)\cdot w(v)$.

If this explanation isn't sufficient (it works for me), you could define $\delta(v,e)$ to be 1 if the vertex $v$ is on the edge $e$, and 0 otherwise, and write

$$
\sum_{e\in E_T}w'(e) = 
\sum_{e \in E_T} \sum_{v \in V} \delta(v, e) w(v) =
\sum_{v \in V}\sum_{e \in E_T}\delta(v, e) w(v) =
\sum_{v \in V} d_T(v)\cdot w(v).
$$